# JSP encoding while inserting non-English text in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using Ajax call to insert Indian characters in MySQL database. I am facing an UTF-8 encoding problem in between flow of my application.

When I am inserting the non-English characters directly by JDBC (not using an Ajax call), then it's showing "????" in the database.

When I include

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

in my JSP file, then I receive the following in my database (question marks instead of non-English characters):

> ????????

When I do not include above lines it shows me junk character like this in database:

> àª®à«?àª?àªªà«?àª·à«?àª

Whereas the actual value is

> મખપષ

So the actual problem lies in or after sending insert request to MySQL command in JSP through JDBC jdbc connector.

I have included following tags in all my JSP files to ensure character encoding:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8;charset=UTF-8">
```

I checked MySQL tables are Unicode enabled and I am able to enter correctly non English text through terminal.

How is this problem caused and how can I solve it?

Now, i am able to write using a insert statement only....but when i mix some queries and insert statement then... my application return me following error:
Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
following are my database variables:

```
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci            |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci            |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci            |
| completion_type          | 0                          |
| concurrent_insert        | 1                          |
| connect_timeout          | 10                         |
```

Comment: I see that you've added a new, completely different, question. Please don't do that. Just ask a new question for that by pressing the *Ask Question* button on right top.

Comment: thanks ... sorry i thought it will retain the context...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *When I am inserting the non-English characters directly by JDBC (not using an Ajax call), then it's showing "????" in the database.*

This will only happen when the both sides are perfectly aware of the character encoding differences in each side. Any character which is not covered by the character encoding used on the other side will be replaced by a question mark `?`. Otherwise you would have seen [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

In this particular case, those sides are the Java side and the database side, with the JDBC driver as mediator. To fix this, you need to tell the JDBC driver what encoding those characters are in. You can do that by setting the `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` parameters in the JDBC connection URL.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Then, depending on how you're sending the parameters from the client to server, you possibly also need to fix the request encoding. Given the fact that you're seeing Mojibake when you removes `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`, you're using POST. So that part is fine.

For the case that, if you were using GET to send the parameters, you would need to configure URI encoding in the server side. It's unclear what server you're using, but in case of for example Tomcat, it's a matter of editing the `<Connector>` entry in `/conf/server.xml` as follows:

```xml
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Thanks i was able to insert the nonEnglish character using jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: but actually i was earlier using jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8   connector string which i found somewhere while surfing for the solution....

I noticed the problem in here connector string while going through your reply
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me to solve this issue...

You need to figure out where in the processing chain things are going on.

You say that you have created the tables correctly and that you can enter and display text from your terminal.  You have *something* that is known to be handling these characters correctly, so try the following experiments ... *in this order* ... to isolate where things are going wrong.

1. Using the `mysql` command, attempt to insert a row containing the problem characters, and then to select and display the inserted row.
2. Write a simple Java program to do the same, using the JDBC URLs that your application is currently doing.
3. Modify your app to capture and log the request parameter strings it is receiving from the browser.
4. (If possible) capture the requests as received by your server and as sent by the browser.  Check both the request parameters and the headers.

Answer (score 0):

*One aside:*
Place the directives together without spaces. (You can even combine the attributes inside a single @page.) Because HTTP headers should be set **before** HTML content is written. Because of page buffering this is not strictly needed, but formally yes.

The other answers till now are true.

One additional issue is the database, table and field definitions which all can have a default and actual character set.

Off course one should be really careful, àª®à«?àª?àªªà«?àª·à«?àª might be a wrong display of the correct data, as the displaying program might not be using UTF-8.