# Unicode display incorrectly in Java EE 6 Openshift MySQL

Tags: mysql, jsp, unicode, openshift

I have a Java EE 6 application which need to use Unicode. I tried everything I can (including guidance in this post: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/jboss-mysql-html-forms-encoding-problem) but none works. The problem is I need to append "useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8" to the JDBC MySQL connection string. The details of the solution is here: [JSP encoding while inserting non-English text in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311463/jsp-encoding-while-inserting-non-english-text-in-mysql-database)

Unfortunately, I can't append the connection string in Openshift because the standalone.xml can't be modified. If the gear is restarted, the standalone.xml file will be reset as well. If I use JNDI lookup, it will not work. The only way is to append the JDBC connection string.

Is there any solution? Please, help!

Note: The application server I am using on OpenShift is JBoss 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you modifying standalone.xml as it should be in your local git repo's .openshift/config/ directory.  Once modified, do a git commit/push and it should take.  standalone.xml preconfigures your mysql connection (MysqlDS) so you should be able to just add this and you're off to the races.

Feel free to post to our forums:  https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift